# Detect if environment contains a page break

Tags: environments, code

Is it possible to detect if a custom environment goes over a page break, i.e. get a warning/something I can use for further processing (and preferably also tells me where the page break occurs)?

```
\newenvironment{Test}{\CheckIfPageBreak\PrintPageBreak}{}
```

In document:

```
\begin{Test}
A
A
A
A
\end{Test}
```

results in

```
False
A
A
A
A
```

while

```
\begin{Test}
A
A
/--page break due to long text--/
A
A
\end{Test}
```

results in

```
True
A
A
/--page break--/
A
A
```

Comment: insert a label at start and end and then compare the pagerefs, the zref package may help with numeric comparisons of pageref.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is it still possible to detect that before the environment starts? I just got examples where I got the answer after the environment was finished...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the comment, how can you know before seeing the environment that it will not fit on the page?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I used some of your suggestions, and the solution (also to this question) is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301463/renew-an-already-used-label