# Toggle is not checked

Tags: conditionals

I used the answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301472/61517) for checking if an environment is placed on another page than the enclosing environment. I want to execute other commands as soon as I am on a new page, but only once on that page, even if there are multiple sections `B` on that new page. Thus I modified it as shown here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{envAcounter}
\newcounter{envBcounter}
\newtoggle{newPage}
\togglefalse{newPage}
\newenvironment{A}{%
  \stepcounter{envAcounter}%
  \null\label{env:A:start:\arabic{envAcounter}}%
}{\label{env:A:end:\arabic{envAcounter}}
\togglefalse{newPage}
}%

\newenvironment{B}{%
  \stepcounter{envBcounter}%
  \null\label{env:B:start:\arabic{envBcounter}}%
  \iftoggle{newPage}{}{
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{env:A:start:\arabic{envAcounter}}=%
        \getpagerefnumber{env:B:start:\arabic{envBcounter}}\relax%
    Pagebreak did not take place before starting environment B!% 
  \else
    Pagebreak took place before starting environment B!%
    \toggletrue{newPage}
  \fi}
}{\label{env:B:end:\arabic{envBcounter}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{A}
Text
\begin{B}
SubText
\end{B}
\end{A}
\begin{A}
Text2
\newpage
\begin{B}
SubText2
\end{B}
\begin{B}
SubText3
\end{B}
\end{A}
\end{document}
```

The idea was to set a `true`-value as soon as the first page break is detected, and then afterwards skip the check. But that does not work, I still get the check if I am at a new page executed every time I am in environment `B`. Why is the toggle not working as expected, and how can I fix that?

Comment: Try `\global\togglefalse` etc. Your working inside of groups

Comment: Yes, that works. Is there an extended explanation, when I have to use `\global`?

Comment: Otherwise, the toggle is local to the environment

Comment: @arc_lupus: The `\toggle.....` stuff is (as far as now) nothing different than a wrapper for a plain `\if....` conditional. The boolean states `true` and `false` 'survive' only within a group, and `\ifsomething .... \fi` is a group, the environment is also a group. Your state must be available after the conditional or the environment ends, as such, you must `\global`ize the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain things in (La)TeX have limited scope. If you want its modifications to survive the group within which the change is made, you have to ensure that it's made `\global`ly (or, perhaps, in such a way that it happens after the group):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,etextools}

\newcommand{\showtoggle}[1]{#1: \iftoggle{#1}{true}{false}\par}

\newtoggle{mytoggle}
%\togglefalse{mytoggle}% default

\newenvironment{myenv}%
  {\bigskip
   begin: \showtoggle{mytoggle}}
  {end: \showtoggle{mytoggle}}

\begin{document}

\togglefalse{mytoggle}
\begin{myenv}% false
inside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% false
\end{myenv}% false

outside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% false

\toggletrue{mytoggle}
\begin{myenv}% true
inside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% true
\end{myenv}% true

outside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% true

\togglefalse{mytoggle}
\begin{myenv}% false
\toggletrue{mytoggle}
inside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% true
\end{myenv}% true

outside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% false

\togglefalse{mytoggle}
\begin{myenv}% false
\AfterGroup{\toggletrue{mytoggle}}
inside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% false
\end{myenv}% false

outside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% true

\togglefalse{mytoggle}
\begin{myenv}% false
\global\toggletrue{mytoggle}
inside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% true
\end{myenv}% true

outside: \showtoggle{mytoggle}% true

\end{document}
```

*Counters* are different...